# More concise option to `separate` a column in R (maybe through some RegEx)?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe where I want to separate a column that contains month and year:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  month_year = c("Januar / Janvier 1990", "Februar / Février 1990","März / Mars 1990")
)

# df
#               month_year
# 1  Januar / Janvier 1990
# 2 Februar / Février 1990
# 3       März / Mars 1990
```

The following works, but seems quite a bit clunky:

```
df %>% 
  separate(month_year, c("month","nothing","nothing2", "year"), sep = " ") %>%
  select(-starts_with("nothing"))

#     month year
# 1  Januar 1990
# 2 Februar 1990
# 3    März 1990
```

Is there a more concise option to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1) separate** Use NA to omit the unwanted field like this:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate(month_year, c("month", NA, "year"))
##     month year
## 1  Januar 1990
## 2 Februar 1990
## 3    März 1990
```

@Otto pointed out that this has problems in UTF8.  If that is your situation add the sep= value shown.  `separate` uses a default of `"[^[:alnum:]]+"` which does not handle UTF8 but we can specify either of these instead:

- `"[^\\p{L}\\d]+"` .  This replaces `"[:alnum:]"` with `"\\p{L}"` which is any letter in any language and `"\\d"` which is any digit, or
- `"(*UCP)[^[:alnum:]]+"` which uses a unicode specifier as a prefix

This shows an example.  First we create an input df2 which exhibits the problem and then we use one of the above two sep values with it.

```
df <- data.frame(
  month_year = c("Januar / Janvier 1990", "Februar / Février 1990","März / Mars 1990"))
df2 <- df %>% mutate(month_year = iconv(month_year, to = "UTF8"))

df2 %>% separate(month_year, c("month", NA, "year"), sep = "[^\\p{L}\\d]+")
##     month year
## 1  Januar 1990
## 2 Februar 1990
## 3    März 1990
```

**2) read.table** and here is a base solution:

```
read.table(text = df[[1]], col.names = c("month", NA, NA, "year"))[-(2:3)]
##     month year
## 1  Januar 1990
## 2 Februar 1990
## 3    März 1990
```

**3) read.pattern** This picks out the desired fields using read.pattern. `(\\w+)` captures the first word and `(\\d+)` captures the year.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "(\\w+).* (\\d+)"
read.pattern(text = df[[1]], pattern = pat, col.names = c("month", "year"))
##     month year
## 1  Januar 1990
## 2 Februar 1990
## 3    März 1990
```

Comment: Regarding option 1), in my environment, `é` and `ä` are interpreted as field separators if I call `separate()` without specifying `sep=" "`. The output is: month  year
1  Januar  1990
2 Februar vrier
3       M  Mars
Warning message:
Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 2 rows [2, 3].

Comment: My locale is `en_GB.UTF-8`. Setting `sep="[^\\p{L}\\d]+"` seems to have the desired effect.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this by converting the `month_year` column to UTF8.  Have moved my solution previously shown in comments to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

### base R

```r
strcapture("^(.*)\\s+/.*\\s+([^\\s]+)$", df$month_year, proto = c(month="", year=1L))
#     month year
# 1  Januar 1990
# 2 Februar 1990
# 3    März 1990
```

Perhaps a little clunky:

```r
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame,
    lapply(strsplit(df$month_year, "\\s+"), function(z) z[c(1, length(z))])),
  c("month", "year"))
```

### dplyr

A *ever-so-slight* reduction of your code, with a different regex:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  separate(month_year, c("month", "ign", "year"), "[ /]+") %>%
  select(-ign)
```

or

```r
df %>%
  mutate(month_year = gsub("/.* ", "", month_year)) %>%
  separate(month_year, c("month", "year"), " ")
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `word` from `stringr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(month = word(month_year, 1),
         year = word(month_year, 4), .keep="unused")
```

```
    month year
1  Januar 1990
2 Februar 1990
3    März 1990
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following base R code with `read.table` + `gsub`

```
read.table(
  text = c(names(df), gsub("\\s+.*\\s+", "_", df$month_year)),
  sep = "_",
  header = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
    month year
1  Januar 1990
2 Februar 1990
3    MΣrz 1990
```

Answer (score 2):

**Tidyverse + stringr**

```
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(year = as.numeric(str_extract(.$month_year, '\\d+'))) %>%
        mutate(month = str_extract(.$month_year, '[^ /]+') )
              month_year year   month
1  Januar / Janvier 1990 1990  Januar
2 Februar / Février 1990 1990 Februar
3       März / Mars 1990 1990    März
```

`'\\d+'` captures all digits; `[^ /]` captures substring before the first occurrence of  `/`.